# BATCH FILE : Export mysql by table

Tags: mysql, batch-file

good day . I need some help please about code on how can i create a batch file that export mysql database by table.

```
FOR %%D IN `mysql -uroot -e "SHOW TABLES from sample"` do echo %%D mysqldump -uroot sample %%D > %%D.sql
```

help. thank you.

Comment: Sir. this is my code

    **@echo off 
    SET path=C:\Users\neca\Desktop cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin 

    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%D IN ('mysql -uroot -e "SHOW TABLES from sample"') do echo %%D

    pause**

BUT in my db I only have 2 tables (sample and test). Why is it that the
output of this code is 

    **Tables_in_sample 
    sample 
    test**

where Tables_in_sample is a table that i did not made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with next command:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%D IN ('mysql -uroot -e "SHOW TABLES from sample"') do @echo %%D
```

Then you could refine and modify output with some `%%~D` [modifiers](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Next resource on [for /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) command.

Comment: sir. what does "tokens=* mean? what should i pud? thank you for your responds.

Comment: @JosefZ - You missed the closing `"` on the tokens section.
@xXxrk04 - `"tokens=*"` means proces the entire line and ignore any delimiters. He could also have used `"delims="` - it's just personal preference.

Comment: Mea culpa, mea maxima culpa! Thank you, @SomethingDark (and being a habitual paranoid one could use both `"tokens=* delims="` as well :))

Comment: Sir. this is my code 

@echo off
SET path=C:\Users\neca\Desktop
cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%D IN ('mysql -uroot -e "SHOW TABLES from sample"') do echo %%D

pause

BUT

in my db only have 2 table sample and test. why is it that the output of this code is 

Tables_in_sample
sample
test

where Tables_in_sample is a table that i did not made.

Comment: Sir. this is my code

    **@echo off 
    SET path=C:\Users\neca\Desktop cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin 

    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%D IN ('mysql -uroot -e "SHOW TABLES from sample"') do echo %%D

    pause**

BUT in my db I only have 2 tables (sample and test). Why is it that the
output of this code is 

    **Tables_in_sample 
    sample 
    test**

where Tables_in_sample is a table that i did not made.